# Pod in Running State but in Pod's Events: Warning Unhealthy kubelet Readiness probe failed: command "/bin/bash -c /ready-probe.sh" timed out

Tags: kubernetes

What does it mean for a Running Pod an Event:

`Warning  Unhealthy kubelet Readiness probe failed: command "/bin/bash -c /ready-probe.sh" timed out` ? :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl describe pod cassandra-0
Name:             cassandra-0
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             k8s-eu-1-worker-1/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Start Time:       Tue, 07 Nov 2023 19:18:49 +0100
Labels:           app=cassandra
                  apps.kubernetes.io/pod-index=0
                  controller-revision-hash=cassandra-58c99f489d
                  statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=cassandra-0
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: ee11d6b9b5dfade09500ccf53d2d1e4e04aaf479c4502d76f6ce0044c6683ac4
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.200.12/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.200.12/32
Status:           Running
IP:               192.168.200.12
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.200.12
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/cassandra
Containers:
  cassandra:
    Container ID:   containerd://1386bc65f0f9c11eb9351435578c37efb7081fbbf0acd7a9b2ab6d3507576e0f
    Image:          gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13
    Image ID:       gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra@sha256:7a3d20afa0a46ed073a5c587b4f37e21fa860e83c60b9c42fec1e1e739d64007
    Ports:          7000/TCP, 7001/TCP, 7199/TCP, 9042/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 07 Nov 2023 19:18:51 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      500m
      memory:   1Gi
    Readiness:  exec [/bin/bash -c /ready-probe.sh] delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE:           512M
      HEAP_NEWSIZE:            100M
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS:         cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
      CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME:  K8Demo
      CASSANDRA_DC:            DC1-K8Demo
      CASSANDRA_RACK:          Rack1-K8Demo
      POD_IP:                   (v1:status.podIP)
    Mounts:
      /srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-1 from k8s-eu-1-worker-1 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-nzb6p (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  k8s-eu-1-worker-1:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  k8s-eu-1-worker-1-cassandra-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-nzb6p:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  7m28s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/cassandra-0 to k8s-eu-1-worker-1
  Normal   Pulling    7m28s  kubelet            Pulling image "gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13"
  Normal   Pulled     7m28s  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13" in 383ms (383ms including waiting)
  Normal   Created    7m28s  kubelet            Created container cassandra
  Normal   Started    7m27s  kubelet            Started container cassandra
  Warning  Unhealthy  7m     kubelet            Readiness probe failed: command "/bin/bash -c /ready-probe.sh" timed out // <-------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A readiness error occurs when a container within a pod does not pass the configured readiness probe checks. This error indicates that the container is not yet ready to receive and serve incoming traffic or requests. When Kubernetes detects this failure, it stops routing traffic to the problematic container and waits for it to become ready by passing the readiness probe checks.

Some of the possible reasons for this failure are:

- The probe script is not executed.
- The probe script is executed but it fails.
- The probe script is executed but it takes too long to complete.

Attaching here as well the reference [documentation](https://www.codemotion.com/magazine/devops/cloud/k8s-readiness-probe-failed-error/) including the steps how to troubleshoot the readiness probe failed errors.